# C++ Excel and name sheet

Tags: c++, excel

I have a problem with the name of sheet. If it gives a name in the code, it is visible in its entirety, but when I use a variable, the name is truncated.

```
    ExcelApplication->Connect();
    Wb = ExcelApplication->Workbooks->Open( sciezka.c_bstr() );
    
    Sheets = Wb->get_Sheets(); // Ustawienie na zakładce 'zestawienie', która jest uzupełniana
    Ws = Sheets->get_Item( TVariant(1) );
    //Ws->Name = L"Zestawienie"; // Ok
    // ws->Name = s.c_str(); // name is truncated to 4 chars
```

Comment: So the problem is the `s` variable? But you haven't posted any code at all showing the `s` variable. I can't help with code I cannot see.

Comment: Ja just find solution. Function "Name" need widestring variable so instead of c_str() should be c_bstr()